# Call repository method from entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to call repository method on entity? 
I mean something like this

```
$article = $em->getRepository('Entities\Articles')->findOneBy(array('id' => $articleId));
$category = $em->getRepository('Entities\Categories')->findOneBy(array('id' => 86));

$article->addArticleToCategory($category);
```

Where addArticleToCategory is method in repository (just an example code)

```
public function addArticleToCategory($category){
    $categoryArticles = new CategoryArticles();
    $categoryArticles->setArticle(!!/** This is where I want to have my variable $article from this method call **/!!);
    $categoryArticles->setCategory($category);
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($categoryArticles);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```

What is the best way to do it?

Also I want to know is it a good practice to put custom set/create methods in repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition you can't call a method of your repository class from an entity object... This is basic object-oriented programming.

I think you should create `addArticle` function in the `Category` entity, something like this:

```
function addArticle($article)
{
   $this->articles[] = $article;
   $article->setCategory($this);
}
```

And then you do

```
$article = $em->getRepository('Entities\Articles')->findOneBy(array('id' => $articleId));
$category = $em->getRepository('Entities\Categories')->findOneBy(array('id' => 86));

$category->addArticle($article);
$em->persist($category);
$em->flush();
```

If the cascades are correctly configured, this will work

Comment: So are repositories even used to hold set/add methods? Or they are good only for get methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own repository manager and create a method for your needs.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories

Comment: This is exactly what I did in my example :) The question was more about set/add methods in repositories. And the best way to do it.

Comment: The code in repositories shouldn't create new objects, only manipulate the entity.

Your code it's better placed in a controller

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is what I wanted to know.