# Use a repository method to define a __toString() for an entity

Tags: symfony

Let's say I have a "book" entity class. It is linked to an "author" entity class. In my book repository, I have a method called `getTitle()` that concatenates information from the book and the author attributes.

Now, I want that from any of my views, when I call `{{thisBook}}`, the getTitle() result is displayed.

Instinctivelly, I suppose that it would requires to create a `__toString()` method in my book entity, that calls the getTitle() method of my book repository. But everyone advise against it (see : [Call repository method from entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422079/call-repository-method-from-entity), [How to access repository methods for an entity in symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712889/how-to-access-repository-methods-for-an-entity-in-symfony2) ...).

Should I "force" the system? Or is there a cleaner way to do so? This sounds so trivial, there must be an "official" and easy way to do so...

Comment: You could use https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: Just use `fetch="EAGER"` for ManyToOne to avoid multiple queries and use `__toString()` method to show what you need. After that, everytime you will echo your book, you will get what you need: `{{ myBook }}` ------> <TITLE> by <AUTHOR_NAME>

Comment: As you said, it's not OK to force the system.

Comment: @Veve, data_transformers seem awesome, but it seems that it is onlu used in a form, right? My context goes beyond form...

Comment: @GasKa, I like your solution, however I wonder what happens if I need more "connexion" to build my string? Like : I have "book", connected to "author", connected to "place" (book is not connected to place, the information goes through the "author", for the sake of the question). Can I access "place" from "book"?

Comment: @GGTT actually you can do that, but it's not ideal

Comment: Yes ? I tried it and it works fine. When you say it is not ideal, is it because of easthetical reason? or performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem in defining the method in the entity itself if it doesn't include access to external resources. So if all you do is concatenate values from the entity itself, it's no problem (google about so called `anemic` and `rich` entities).

Using something like service is definitely overkill in this case. Basically you should not access services (and repositories or anything else that actually does some work) in entities, they are just a storage. But accessing values of the entity itself or even values of related entites is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service like `src/Service/SetupHelper.php`:

```
<?php


namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;

class SetupHelper
{
    private $em;
    private $session;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->getUser()->getName();
    }

    }
}
```

After customize services you can call the functions in any twig like this:

```
<title>{% block title %}{{ SetupHelper.getName() }}!{% endblock %}</title><title>{% block title %}{{ SetupHelper.getName() }}!{% endblock %}</title>
```

Comment: I thought of a similar solution: getting the entitymanager from the twig AppExtention. But it stills requires something heavier than just use the php magic method __toString()...